# Sharepoint 2010 site definition one template to create multiple publishing pages

Tags: 2010, site-definition, provisioning

Im trying to create a publishing site definition where I use one file to provision many templates.

```
eg in onet.xml
 ...
 <Modules>
    <Module Name="Landing" />
    <Module Name="Test" />
    <Module Name="Test2" />
 </Modules>
 ...
  <Modules>
<Module Name="Landing" Url="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;" Path="">
  <File Url="default.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Level="Draft">
      <Property Name="Title" Value="LPALanding" />
      <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/WelcomeLinks.aspx, $Resources:cmscore,PageLayout_WelcomeLinks_Title;" />
      <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_welcomepage_name;" />
  </File>
</Module>
<Module Name="Test" Url="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;" Path="">
      <File Url="default2.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Level="Draft">
          <Property Name="Title" Value="Test" />
          <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/WelcomeLinks.aspx, $Resources:cmscore,PageLayout_WelcomeLinks_Title;" />
          <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_welcomepage_name;" />
      </File>
</Module>
<Module Name="Test2" Url="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;" Path="">
      <File Url="default2.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Level="Draft">
          <Property Name="Title" Value="Test2" />
          <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/WelcomeLinks.aspx, $Resources:cmscore,PageLayout_WelcomeLinks_Title;" />
          <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_welcomepage_name;" />
      </File>
</Module>
```

Does anyone know if this is possible to do as at the moment I am getting the following results

[image: Just shows default and default2]

do  need to set a param to name the file something different when its being provisioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done by using the name attribute on the file

eg

```
 <Module Name="Test" Url="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;" Path="">
      <File Name="Test.aspx" Url="default2.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Level="Draft">
          <Property Name="Title" Value="LPAGloucester" />
          <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/WelcomeLinks.aspx, $Resources:cmscore,PageLayout_WelcomeLinks_Title;" />
          <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_welcomepage_name;" />
      </File>
</Module>
<Module Name="Test2" Url="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;" Path="">
      <File Name="Test2.aspx" Url="default2.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Level="Draft" >
          <Property Name="Title" Value="LPACheltenham" />
          <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/WelcomeLinks.aspx, $Resources:cmscore,PageLayout_WelcomeLinks_Title;" />
          <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_welcomepage_name;" />
      </File>
</Module>
```

just remember to place the aspx on the end of the file name :-)